# AIX not able to run applications in specific directory

Tags: unix, directory, file-permissions, aix

This might be simple problem. But I am stuck with this for weeks now.

We have an AIX server in which we are facing this issue. I am not able to run programs inside a specific directory and its sub directories.

I am getting proper outputs for commands java and scp2 in /opt/FileNet directory. But when I am in /opt/FileNet/RM directory these commands stops working. Outputs are as below.

Java - JVMXM008: Error occured while initialising System ClassException in thread "main" Could not create the Java virtual machine.

SCP2 - Failed to parse installation path.

I have no idea why this is happening. Your thoughts please.

Comment: $PATH also is looking good. 

/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java14/jre/bin:/usr/java14/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/nmon

Comment: What are the exact file permissions on /, /opt, /opt/FileNet, and /opt/FileNet/RM? Including ACLs, if they're present...

Answer (score 0):

```
drwxr-xr-x   24 root     system         4096 Feb 21 2012  opt
drwxr-xr-x   17 jxadmin  wasadmin       4096 Aug 14 08:40 FileNet
drwxrwxr-x   17 jxadmin  wasadmin       4096 Aug 14 08:45 RM
drwxrwxr-x   37 jxadmin  wasadmin       4096 Feb 13 2012  AE (/opt/FileNet/AE, This directory is working as expected)
```

Couldn't find any ACLs.

Comment: this info should be included in your original posting. Also, use `ls -ld  / /opt /opt/FileNet /opt/FileNet/RM` to post this info. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for formatting it for me. `RM` and its subdirectories are having the problem. When we moved one of the subfolders to `/opt/FileNet/` the issue was not there in the folder anymore. So some file permissions in the `RM` directory which is inherited to the subfolders is causing this problem.

Comment: Easiest way to solve is to replace `RM` directory with another directory copying the contents. Tried to rename the `RM` directory and got this error.

`/opt/FileNet$ mv RM RM.old
mv: 0653-401 Cannot rename RM to RM.old:
             The requested resource is busy.`

Comment: The issue turned out to be the underlying mount point permission problem. `/opt/FileNet/RM` was a different partition and mount point didn't have `777` permissions given.

Comment: that's not a good solution, regardless of what your vendor may tell you. Good luck.